# If $f(x) = \dfrac{x - 2011}{11}$, then evaluate $(f \circ f \circ f \circ f \circ f)(x)$

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

If $f(x) = \dfrac{x - 2011}{11}$, then $(f \circ f \circ f \circ f \circ  f)(x)$ is $\cdots$

A. $\frac{x+2011}{x-1}$
B. $\frac{x+2011}{x+1}$
C. $\frac{x-2011}{x+1}$
D. $\frac{x-2011}{x-1}$
E. $\frac{-x+2011}{x-1}$

I find no leading to solve this one. Please help me. 
I thought there is a sort of pattern so that we can find the faster way for it, but it looks like the first composition already makes the thing too complicated.
Can you give me some tips?

Comment: None of them You must have made a mistake in copying the question.

Comment: Indeed, it should be a linear function.

Comment: Looks like the right answer is just a line with big numbers: $(x-32387155)/161051$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: The given answers are incorrect. As for solving the problem, why not try a general case and see if any patterns emerge?

$$f(x) = \frac{x\color{blue}{+b}}{\color{purple}{c}}$$

$$(f\circ f)(x) = \frac{\frac{x+b}{c}+b}{c} = \frac{\frac{x+b+bc}{c}}{c} = \frac{x\color{blue}{+b+bc}}{\color{purple}{c^2}}$$

$$(f\circ f\circ f)(x) = \frac{\frac{x+b+bc}{c^2}+b}{c} = \frac{\frac{x+b+bc+bc^2}{c^2}}{c} = \frac{x\color{blue}{+b+bc+bc^2}}{\color{purple}{c^3}}$$

Notice the geometric progression in the numerators.